# Correct permutations of 4 pairs of parentheses

Tags: combinatorics

What is the number of syntacly correct premutations of these parentheses: $(((()))).$ calculating the total number of permutations is easy, but im not sure how to eliminate the wrong ones, like $(()))((.$

Comment: http://oeis.org/A000108

Comment: Related:  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number.

Comment: A site search for *Catalan numbers* will show many related Questions.